# Multiple android libraries in a Single android application

Tags: android, android-library

I am developing an android application that includes external libraries in it.
1) **com_facebook_android**
2) **com_viewpagerindicator**

I was working fine with single external library (i.e facebook library)but when I try to add second external library that is view pager library **Android Application** shows error. I tried but couldn't figure out that error because this error is not present in any of the resource or in java files of that project. It become visible when I add that external library in it. Following image will help you for better understanding. [image]

Comment: did you add the external JAR? (can be done from project properties > build path)

Comment: What is the error? What does the error log say?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, error log is empty, as you can see in above image error sign is on project name and other folders in that project has no errors.

Comment: Thanx guys issue resolved. The reason for this error was **android-support-v4** library, because it was added twice. :)